# Java textArea display foreign languages

Tags: java

so I have a JTextArea :

```
JTextArea commentTextArea = new JTextArea();
```

And it workes just fine, I can get text from it and put some text in it. But when I have text from other languages like from India I can't see it. I see some empty rectangles.... when I copy the same text to Notepad++ I see all the words OK.
Do You have and ideas how to solve this problem ?

Comment: Please provide more details, preferably a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show the full scope of your issue, as there are many dimensions, where such a problem could reside.

Comment: Can you provide an example of some text that does not render in your JTextArea?

Comment: lets say Khmer language: អ្នកចង់ទៅលេងសៀ

Comment: Well I am not sure what details You need, just create simple JTextArea, start the app and try to past/copy there:   អ្នកចង់ទៅលេងសៀ

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help:

http://www.coderanch.com/t/330837/GUI/java/display-Chinese-TextArea?foo=a

Try entering the text with unicodes: \u1234 for example

Comment: well It's a TextArea I want to be able to type the text, I dont know how to implement this

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use this:

```
 JTextArea commentTextArea = new JTextArea(); 
    Font f=new Font("Shree-Guj-0768W", Font.PLAIN, 17);
    commentTextArea .setFont(f);
```

Output:

```
 हैलो वर्ल्ड
```

Comment: no, for lets say Khmer language it doesn't work: អ្នកចង់ទៅលេងសៀ

Comment: @Pirate in this part you can add Font do you  like:new Font("TimesRoman" ...or new Font("Verdana"

Comment: Well I tried TimesRoman and Verdana and still all I see is set of empty rectangles not Khmer text...

Comment: @Pirate Try now I put new modification

Comment: Well thnx for help but this still is not working ....  I guess I don't have Shree-Guj-0768W installed on my system ? or netbeans? but anyway this will only solve my problem with this language what about others ? That also have those freaky characters ?